# Why does using a set in filter cause "org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to filter a collection of objects, that are in a RDD, based on a field of these objects being in a list.

The approach I am trying the same as here:
[Filter based on another RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26214112/filter-based-on-another-rdd-in-spark)

```
val namesToFilterOn = sc.textFile("/names_to_filter_on.txt").collect.toSet

val usersRDD = userContext.loadUsers("/user.parquet")
```

This works:

```
usersRDD.filter(user =>  Set("Pete","John" ).contains( user.firstName )).first
```

When I try

```
usersRDD.filter(user => namesToFilterOn.contains( user.firstName )).first
```

I get this error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
```

The same error I get when I try this

```
val shortTestList = Set("Pete","John" )

usersRDD.filter(user => shortTestList .contains( user.firstName )).first
```

Why do I get this errer when specifying a Set of names/String in these filter statements?

As far as I can see this should work, I a not specifying the SparkContext anywhere in the filter statements. So why the error? And how not to get the error?

The version of Spark that I am using is 1.5.2.

I also tried to first broadcast the Set of names.

```
val namesToFilterOnBC = sc.broadcast(namesToFilterOn)
usersRDD.filter(user => namesToFilterOnBC.value.contains( user.firstName )).first
```

This leads again to the same error

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.SparkContext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the developers of userContext and solved the issue by not explicitly instantiating userContext but by just importing its functions.

```
import userContext._
sc.loadUsers("/user.parquet")
usersRDD.filter(user => namesToFilterOn.contains( user.firstName )).first
```

instead of

```
val userContext = new UserContext(sc)
userContext.loadUsers("/user.parquet")
usersRDD.filter(user => namesToFilterOn.contains( user.firstName )).first
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `val namesToFilterOn = sc.textFile("/names_to_filter_on.txt").collect.toSet` belongs to an object that contains unserializable vals and hence the error.

When `user => namesToFilterOn.contains( user.firstName )` is transformed into a byte format to send to executors over the wire, Spark checks whether there are any references to unserializable objects and SparkContext is among them.

It appears that Spark found a place where you reference a non-serializable SparkContext and threw the exception.

A solution is to wrap `val namesToFilterOn = sc.textFile("/names_to_filter_on.txt").collect.toSet` or `val shortTestList = Set("Pete","John" )` as separate methods of an `object` in Scala. You can also use the other `val shortTestList` inside the closure (as described in [Job aborted due to stage failure: Task not serializable](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/troubleshooting/javaionotserializableexception.html)) or [broadcast](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) it.

You may find the document [SIP-21 - Spores](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/pending/spores.html) quite informatory for the case.