# Spark broadcast is failing

Tags: apache-spark

I am quite new to spark and trying to filter one RDD based on another as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26259750).

My filter data is in a CSV file in S3. This CSV file is 1.7GB and has ~100M lines. Each line has a unique 10 character long id. My plan is to extract these ids from this CSV file to an in memory set, then broadcast this set and use it to filter another RDD.

My code looks something like this:

```
val sparkContext: SparkContext = new SparkContext()

val filterSet = sparkContext
  .textFile("s3://.../filter.csv") // this is the 1.7GB csv file
  .map(_.split(",")(0)) // each string here has exactly 10 chars (A-Z|0-9)
  .collect()
  .toSet // ~100M 10 char long strings in set.

val filterSetBC = sparkContext.broadcast(filterSet) // THIS LINE IS FAILING

val otherRDD = ...

otherRDD
  .filter(item => filterSetBC.value.contains(item.id))
  .saveAsTextFile("s3://...")
```

I am running this code on AWS EMR on 10 m4.2xlarge (16 vCore, 32 GB memory) EC2 instances and getting below error.

```
18/09/06 17:15:33 INFO UnifiedMemoryManager: Will not store broadcast_2 as the required space (16572507620 bytes) exceeds our memory limit (13555256524 bytes)
18/09/06 17:15:33 WARN MemoryStore: Not enough space to cache broadcast_2 in memory! (computed 10.3 GB so far)
18/09/06 17:15:33 INFO MemoryStore: Memory use = 258.6 KB (blocks) + 1024.0 KB (scratch space shared across 1 tasks(s)) = 1282.6 KB. Storage limit = 12.6 GB.
18/09/06 17:15:33 WARN BlockManager: Persisting block broadcast_2 to disk instead.
18/09/06 17:18:54 WARN BlockManager: Putting block broadcast_2 failed due to exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1073741865.
18/09/06 17:18:54 WARN BlockManager: Block broadcast_2 could not be removed as it was not found on disk or in memory
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1073741865
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.IdentityObjectIntMap.clear(IdentityObjectIntMap.java:382)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.util.MapReferenceResolver.reset(MapReferenceResolver.java:65)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.reset(Kryo.java:865)
    at com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:630)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializationStream.writeObject(KryoSerializer.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializationStream.writeAll(Serializer.scala:140)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.SerializerManager.dataSerializeStream(SerializerManager.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(BlockManager.scala:1101)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(BlockManager.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.DiskStore.put(DiskStore.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1099)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1018)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1083)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putIterator(BlockManager.scala:841)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.putSingle(BlockManager.scala:1404)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.writeBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:123)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.<init>(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcastFactory.newBroadcast(TorrentBroadcastFactory.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.broadcast.BroadcastManager.newBroadcast(BroadcastManager.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.broadcast(SparkContext.scala:1482)
```

As far as I understand from the logs the set I am trying to broadcast is around ~15GB. Normally 100Mx10 chars is ~1GB but with some java overheads I would expected it to be around ~5-6GB.

**Question 1:** Why is my set data is so huge? How can I minimize it?

Still, I configured my executors to consume 22GB (executor-memory) + 2GB (spark.executor.memoryOverhead) memory.

**Question 2:** Why does spark say it is exceeding memory limit (12.6GB)? Where does this 12.6GB limit come from?

I guess I terribly messed up with the `spark-submit` parameters. Here are they:

```
--deploy-mode cluster 
--class com.example.MySparkJob
--master yarn
--driver-memory 24G
--executor-cores 15
--executor-memory 22G
--num-executors 9
--deploy-mode client
--conf spark.default.parallelism=1200
--conf spark.speculation=true
--conf spark.rdd.compress=true
--conf spark.files.fetchTimeout=180s
--conf spark.network.timeout=300s
--conf spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=5000
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true   // also tried without this parameter, no changes
--conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=0
--conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2G
--conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
--conf spark.kryo.registrator=com.example.MyKryoRegistrator
--driver-java-options -XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

Comment: i think its all because of memory settings [see](https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/mastering-apache-spark-book/blob/master/spark-UnifiedMemoryManager.adoc) further to understand and fix

Comment: I would not recommend broadcast so huge dataset at all. Why don't you try regular join for these datasets? Alternatively, you may split 100M records, let's say by 100K records, and broadcast one bucket, join, clear, take next one. Then filter out unmarked null values.

Answer (score 0):

1st Please don’t assign such a huge driver memory 4 Gb is enough, 2nd Executor cores 15 is way to huge 3-4 is enough( this will give more executor instead of only few)
3rd if you have more memory increase the Executor from 9 to 45 ( if not then make Executor 18 And Executor men to 16)